# What does "git checkout - ." do?

Tags: git

I wanted to revert all local changes with

```
git checkout -- .
```

but accidently did

```
git checkout - .
```

and it made lots of local modifications that I can't understand at all.

What does the second command do and is it possible to revert what was done?

Comment: If it does anything, it's a bug... can't find out how it can happen when reading http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: The single - would be ignored.

Comment: `git checkout .` (without any dashes) works for me fine.

Comment: @CharlesB @Layke No, specifying `-` as the branch to check out is well defined and documented. It's equivalent to `@{-1}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`git checkout -` checks out the previously checked out branch. So I would assume that `git checkout - .` will replace the contents of the working copy with the contents of the previously checked out branch.

You can not undo that, but since you wanted to reset the contents of your working dir anyways, why don’t you just run `git checkout -- .`?

You might want to use `git reset --hard` in the future to undo all changes against the current branch. It also resets the index.